Can messages be sent directly to the built-in Event Hubs endpoint in Azure IoT Hub?
Can messages be sent to the built-in Event Hubs-compatible endpoint in Azure IoT Hub?
I have a service that consumes messages on the built-in endpoint. Now, I need to inject artificial messages and want to send them to the same service. Could I bypass any device or IoT Hub and send messages to the built-in endpoint directly?

This is not supported.
The official docs state

This endpoint is Event Hubs-compatible, which enables you to use any of the mechanisms the Event Hubs service supports for reading messages.

(emphasis mine)
But this isn't very clear about whether it is possible.
So I tried it on my own using a Kafka client, and got the following error:

Failed to produce message: kafka server: The client is not authorized to access this topic


That's correct, only the devices can ingest their events to the built-in event hub endpoint, so as a quick workaround you can create a virtual device for your producer and using a REST POST request to send an event to the pipeline or another solution can be used an Azure Stream Analytics job for Fan-IN pipelines.
